# Ksql Can't find any functions with the name 'COUNT_DISTINCT'

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am running ksql cli using

```
docker run --net=host --interactive --tty confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:latest http://localhost:8088
```

I have created a stream

```
CREATE STREAM RAW (`nodeId` INT,`data` STRING) WITH (kafka_topic='raw-data', value_format='JSON',partitions=3);
```

When I run query for count_distinct

```
SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(`nodeId`) FROM RAW EMIT CHANGES;
```

It says

```
Can't find any functions with the name 'COUNT_DISTINCT'
```

The documentation specifies this function

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/aggregate-functions/

Comment: Don't use latest Docker image tag. Use a specific version. (it's possible that latest is not pushed / updated on each release)

Comment: It does not work with 5.4.10 tag also

Comment: That's an old tag. Latest Confluent Platform is around 7.3.1

Comment: On docker hub both server and cli have latest 5.4.10 tags
https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksql-server/tags

Comment: Those images aren't the latest deployments. Use this for the server  https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-server , as mentioned at https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guided by @OneCricketeer solved by using latest docker images as described in https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html